# How to prepare 3 nodes in MapR

Tags: configuration, bigdata, mapr

I am new to the big data world. I wanted to install a 3 nodes MapR cluster in Centos 7. But i do not know how to prepare 3 nodes before I proceed to the installation of MapR. Could anyone please provide some guidelines on how to ready/configure 3 nodes?

Answer (score 0):

The link below along with its subsections will give you details about preparing the nodes for installation. 
https://maprdocs.mapr.com/52/AdvancedInstallation/PreparingEachNode.html

If you are using web installer, make sure you disable SElinux.